# Adding service reference to WCF project in WinForms project - error TCP error code 10061

Tags: wcf

I have multiple WCF projects that I'm trying to reference in a WinForms project. I can see several of the projects when I attempt to add a service reference, but one is not displayed and refuses to let me add it, even if I type the address in manually. When I do that I get:

Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'net.tcp://localhost:14007/DispatchPuller/mex'.
Could not connect to net.tcp://localhost:14007/DispatchPuller/mex. The connection attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:01.0062012. TCP error code 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:14007. 
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:14007

As far as I can tell all the services are set up the same way. Here's two, the top of one which gives me the error:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="PASWCFDispatchPuller.DispatchPuller" behaviorConfiguration="tcpbehaviuor">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="nettcpDispatchPuller" contract="PASWCFDispatchPuller.IDispatchPuller">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="mexDispatchPuller" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:12007/DispatchPuller"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>

      <service name="PASWCFDispatchPuller.StateUpdate" behaviorConfiguration="tcpbehaviuor">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="nettcpStateUpdate" contract="PASWCFDispatchPuller.IStateUpdate">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="mexStateUpdate" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:12007/StateUpdate"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>

    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <!--<behavior >-->
        <behavior name="tcpbehaviuor">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
            set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
            set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
            to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I have no problem adding a reference to the bottom service. Changing the port for the top one also does nothing. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: For adding reference to the service configured using this config, you should try to point to address net.tcp://localhost:12007/StateUpdate/mex. Are you sure you are trying with that address as the error message shows a different URL?

Comment: I edited the original post as the config info wasn't being fully displayed. The error shows the first service. The second service I can add fine.